# Django syntax error in URLConf

Tags: django, urlconf

I'm trying to create a named URL that I can refer to in my templates to point to a page with various parameters but I am getting a syntax error for the following line:

```
    (r'^page/(?P<page_id>\d+)/(?P<page_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'cms.views.detail', name='page_view'),
```

If I remove the name='page_view' part, the error goes away.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work in the same way creating a tuple like `x = (1, 2, foo=3)` is incorrect.  See @tlunter's answer about using the `django.conf.urls.defaults.url` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it change if you put the url() around it instead of just parentheses?